# React: TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

While trying to set value in Parent Class from value fetched from Child. I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Parent Class

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      favoritecolor: "ParentValue RED"
    };
    }

    nameParent(e) {
    this.setState({favoritecolor: e})
    console.log(e); // I am getting the value here from Child. But how to use setState ?
    }
  
    render() {  
    let variableName = ''; 
    return (   
      <div>
        <h1>Value from Child is {this.state.favoritecolor}</h1> 
        <Child nameFn={this.nameParent}/>
      </div>       
      
    );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

**Child Class**

```
export class Child extends React.Component {

    onHClick(e) {
       this.props.nameFn(e); 
    }   

    render() {                
        return (
            <h1 onClick = {this.props.nameFn('Blue Black Green')}>
                Value from parent is = {this.props.name}
            </h1>
        )
     }
}
```

Because of this I am unable to use setState to update state.

Comment: Replace `nameParent(e) {` by `nameParent = (e) => {` to scope `this` to the class level.

Comment: @MaartenDev Doing this i am getting - Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Comment: This is because you directly invoke the `nameFn` in your `Child`, I have provided an Answer as solution to this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors, the first one is related to `this` usage in the `Header` component. You can replace

```
nameParent(e) {
```

by

```
nameParent = (e) => {
```

to scope `this` to the class level.

The second error is caused by the `Child` component because it directly invokes the provided function:

```
<h1 onClick = {this.props.nameFn('Blue Black Green')}>
```

It should be refactored to the following to fix the error:

```
render() {                
    return (
        <h1 onClick = {() => this.props.nameFn('Blue Black Green')}>
            Value from parent is = {this.props.name}
        </h1>
    )
 }
```

Comment: @maartenDev: what is the use of 'e' that you have used??

Comment: The `e` contains the onClick event, it can be replaced with `() => this.props.nameFn('Blue Black Green')` if you don't need access to the`event` data.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the function to the `this` of the class:

```
<Child nameFn={this.nameParent.bind(this)}/>
```